# Containers component with react-mobx

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I would like create `container` with Mobx (like Redux) in React project.

I don't want `inject` directly in my component, i want separate my logic/view code.

Anyone have already create container with mobx ? What is the best practice ?

My actual code :

```
class CategoriesContainers extends React.Component {

  state = {
    categories: [],
    presentations: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCategories();
    this.fetchPresentations();
  }

  async fetchCategories() {
    try {
      const categories = await getAllCategories();
      return this.setState({ categories });
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
  }

  async fetchPresentations() {
    try {
      const presentations = await getAllPresentations();
      return this.setState({ presentations });
    } catch (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Categories
        categories={this.state.categories}
        presentations={this.state.presentations}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

With mobx I don't use container components, I let mobx do the its magic between the view and the model. Logic is only present in the model, the view is for displaying it. You might still need a Container-like component, but only to wire the model with the view. Or you can use a Provider and @inject instead if you prefer.

With this you end up with a natural view / logic separation. Also, the model is easy to test, no need for any React magic.

Simplified ES6 code:

```
class Model {
   @observable categories = [];
   @observable presentations = [];

   fetchData() { ... }
}

@observer
class View extends React.Component {
   return() {
       ...
   }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.model = new Model();
        this.model.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        return <View model=model />;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You use only one store ? AppStore with categories, presentations, etc ? Or CategoriesStore ?

Comment: I usually end up with less store than I plan in the beginning. My goal is to have one store per domain plus one global store for the generic things.